# order by desc didnt not arrange my data

Tags: c#, asp.net

once there are new data insert to my DB my rcount will increase by 1, what am i trying to do is to display latest inserted record to users, but i cant get my expected result

**rCount in my datebase**

1

2

3

4

5

**output**

5

4

3

1

2

**expected output**

5

4

3

2

1

```
 "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rCount DESC) AS 'RowNumber' 
 FROM [MovieListTable]"
```

Comment: why do you need to use the row number in the first place?

Comment: to display a row number for end user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the row number you should introduce a numeric primary key (i.e. `Id`) and make it an Identity column. Now you can just select the row that has the maximum `Id` value:

```
select top 1 * from MovieListTable order by Id desc
```

Or to get all rows:

```
select  * from MovieListTable order by Id desc
```

Comment: if i put top 1, my output will only display 1 record =(

Comment: @CheemunLow: Added to answer - use the Id for display purposes